# Alternative to KNN

Tags: classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I have been working with a custom classification model with some success, and I was wondering if there is a package in Python or R does the same thing. Regular KNN chooses a K and does classification based on the K nearest points, regardless of distance. What I've been doing instead is choosing a distance, and doing the classification based on all points less than the given distance from my point in question, regardless of the number of points. It works even better with distance weighting.  Of course, like regular KNN, scaling X's is essential for it to work (it also helps to give the distance threshold). Is there a package in Python or R that does this?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsClassifier.html

Comment: In R https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/dbscan/html/frNN.html and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679142/fixed-radius-nearest-neighbours-with-sets) question might be interesting.